# How to set permission by InstallShield?

Tags: permissions, installshield, sql-scripts

I create database in InstallShield 2010 by Sql script and it has this error.

```
Error 27506.Error executing SQL script creatdb.sql.
lin7.CREATE DATABASE failed. Some file names listed could not be created. Check related errros.
```

I think my script is right because I check that in Sql server management and my problem is doesn’t set permission.
Which user I set permission? Administrator or users or everyone …

It resolved!

I right-clicked in folder and set full control to user!
[image]

Comment: Do a logging and find out if it is installshield error or error from SQL .